# species that alerts predators in order to mate

Tags: species-identification

I read once about a species of animal that engages in, and please forgive me for the terminology but I cannot for the life of me think of any other way to describe it, mutually-assured destructive sexual blackmail.
If a male attempts to mate with a female, and the female shows signs that she is going to reject the male's advance, the male will start making a loud call that will attract this species' common predator.
Essentially, the male is threatening the female that they will both get eaten if she doesn't accept his advance.

I can't remember what the name of this species was and I really do not like what it's doing to my search history.
**What species, if any, engage in this type of behavior?
What terminology should one use to describe this behavior?**

I tried asking ChatGPT first (less judgmental) but came up empty.
There's a species of orb-weaving spider that will mimic the web vibrations of prey struggling to get free when a female seems likely to reject his advance, in the hopes that the female will accept the male's advances in order to avoid being mistakenly identified as prey.
There's the vampire jumping spider, which risks predation during courtship displays.
Neither of those quite fits the pattern I'm thinking of, where the male exposes both himself and his potential mate to predation.

If you downvote this question, I... completely understand.

Comment: A similar phenomenon occurs in begging nestling birds: https://www.nature.com/articles/nature.2013.12774

Answer (score 2):

I finally found an answer, probably after getting put on some kind of watch list:
[**water striders.**](https://doi.org/10.1038/ncomms1051)
If the female looks like she's going to reject the male, the male will tap on the water surface to attract fish.
The female, being closer to the water, is more likely to be eaten.

Comment: Excellent answer, what a memorable phenomenon. Not sure, but for the term for this you might try [english.se], with the tag [single-word-requests].